# Cisco ASA 5505 as a client

Tags: cisco-vpn, vpn

I want to replace a vpnc client with a Cisco ASA 5505. Is it possible to use the Cisco ASA 5505 running version 8.2(5) as a VPN client (not site-to-site)? If so, please point me to the instructions or an example config. Thanks

Here is the config I used and it works now:

```
vpnclient server vpn.example.com
vpnclient mode client
vpnclient vpngroup MyGroupName password MyGroupPassword
vpnclient vpnclient username MyUserName password MyUserPassword
vpnclient enable
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just setup a site to site VPN? That's the proper thing to do.

Comment: Why not site-to-site?  Passing traffic that's not initiated by the VPN endpoint is the definition of a site-to-site, which I assume you're doing?

Comment: I agree a true site-to-site is the ideal solution, however I don't have the option in this case as I only have client credentials.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get the EasyVPN working. I recently switched my 5505 to be EasyVPN Clients and my 5520 is the EasyVPN server.  It makes a world of difference. Site-to-Site is nice if the remote site has a static IP. If not and the IP address changes then down goes your VPN connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to use ASA 5505 as an Easy VPN Remote. In fact, this is one of Cisco's recommended ways of using 5505s. Here's the document:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa72/configuration/guide/ezvpn505.html

Comment: Added the config I used to my question.